# How to write where without fieldname in laravel ORM query

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

The given sql query is working fine (**update** : please check the full query).

```
SELECT * FROM items where (
    select if((select count(*) from item_offers where (some_id_field = items.id or other_id_field = items.id) <= 0, true, false)
);
```

**full query:**

```
SELECT * FROM items where (
    select if(
        (select count(*) from item_offers where (item_offers.listed_item_id = items.id or item_offers.offer_item_id = items.id) and (item_offers.accepted_at is not null and item_offers.cancelled_at is null))<= 0
    , true, false)
);
```

The condition is that, on the second table, If I find positive (one or more) row count, where i find the items id, then, i should not return the result from items table.

i want to write something like this in laravel query:

```
Item::where(condition is true)->get()
```

i have tried using where, whereRaw and all possible combination i could find in the documentation. is there a way to write where without fieldname.

**conclusion :**

> please check the second answer by @M Khalid Junaid. which is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eloquent relations you could easily get items where there are no related records are present in item_offers

```
class Item extends Model{

    public function item_offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ItemOffers', 'some_id_field','id');
    }
}
```

In query builder you could write

```
$items = Item::doesntHave('item_offers')->get();
```

For updated query

> SELECT * FROM items where (
>       select if((select count(*) from item_offers where (some_id_field = items.id or other_id_field = items.id) <= 0, true, false)
>   );

You could rewrite it with left join like

```
select i.*
from items 
left join item_offers io on (io.some_id_field = i.id or io.other_id_field = i.id)
where io.id is null
```

using query builder you could write it as

```
DB::table('items as i')
    ->leftJoin('item_offers as io', function ($join) {
        $join->on('io.some_id_field', '=', 'i.id')
             ->orWhere('io.other_id_field', '=', 'i.id');
    })
   ->whereNull('io.id')
   ->get()
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid. can you please answer to the updated sql query in the question. there is no foreign key constraint in between the tables

Comment: @M Khalid Junai. is it possible to write eloquent query on the sql query without using join.

Comment: @TomonsoEjang Eloquent works with relations as you said there is no relation between your tables then how would you expect it to work

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid. Is there any way around to implement this in laravel. i'm updating the full query.

Comment: @TomonsoEjang Yes there is a work around if you can confirm that `some_id_field`  and `other_id_field` are related to your items table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174319/discussion-between-tomonso-ejang-and-m-khalid-junaid).

Answer (score 1):

For updated question posting  it as a new answer

Item offers table relates to items using 2 attributes `listed_item_id` & `offer_item_id`, In your item model you could define these associations as

```
class Item extends Model{

    public function listed_offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ItemOffers', 'listed_item_id','id');
    }

    public function item_offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ItemOffers', 'offer_item_id','id');
    }
}
```

To check absence of these relations you could write it as

```
$items = Item::doesntHave('listed_offers')->doesntHave('item_offers')->get();
```